# find out unrepetitive, unique data pair in matlab

Tags: matlab, find, unique

I have a set of data looks like this:

data =

4  35
4  36
4  37
4  39
4  50
6  24
6  35
6  36
6  39
6  50
6  78
10 24
10 35
10 36
10 39
...

The actual matrix is in the order of 70000 X 2. What I want is to form a matrix containing all the unique data pair, so each element is not the same as the previous ones, would be look like

result =

4  35
6  24
10 36

I am think about a method like this
Step 1. find out all the index of unique column 1, in this case would be

index =

1
6
12

Step 2. Do a for-loop like this

```
result = data(index);

for j = 1:length(index)

  if result(j,2) == result(j-1,2)

     result(j) = data(index+1)

  end

end
```

Here comes a problem, I have the possibility of getting some result like this

4 35
6 24
10 35

Then it is not unique. However, I don't want to write something like

```
 if result(j,2) = result(j-1,2) ...
     or result(j,2) = result(j-2,2) ...
     or result(j,2) = result(j-3,2) ...
     or result(j,2) = result(j-4,2) ...
 result(j) = data(index+?)
```

that would be even more complicated.

Thank you very much for the help in advance.

Comment: Can you explain your result? Why does it contain `[4 35]` and not `[4 36]`? Why does it contain `[10 36]` and not `[10 24]`?

Comment: @Eitan Hello, yes theoretically [4 36] is also the possible solution, but since I sort answer from low to high (column 2), it is like this.
And if I got [10 24] the 2nd column will be same as [6 24]. Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 6):

try this:

```
unique(data,'rows')
```

> C = unique(A,'rows') treats each row of A as a single entity and returns the unique rows of A. The rows of the matrix C are in sorted order.
>   The 'rows' option does not support cell arrays.

Comment: hi Lucius,
No this doesn't work, it returns the same matrix, but thanks for help !

Comment: -> by unique you mean that every single number has to be unique?

Comment: hi Lucius, yes I would like column 1 and column 2 both be unique :) Sorry for the ambiguity :P

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
I = true(size(data,1),1);
idx = [];
while any(I)
    idx(end+1) = find(I,1,'first');  %#ok
    I = I & all(~bsxfun(@eq, data, data(idx(end),:)),2);
end

result = data(idx,:);
```

Comment: hi Mohsen 
this has the same problem with my for-loop: it select unique value in column 1 but column 2 is still repetitive
thanks for help anyway!

Comment: @quinette I updated the answer. It should consider the second column as well. Note that this approach also works for a matrix with any number of columns.

Comment: hi Mohsen, Thanks a lot for your solution, it works great! Now I need to take some time to understand your code :)

Comment: hi Mohsen, in fact I do need to apply this on a matrix with more columns now :) Which line of your code involve the considering the 2nd column? I need to change that cuz I don't want to considering my 3rd column. Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: here the `idx` returns the position of rows that should be chosen. I think the easiest approach is that you create a new matrix with columns that you want to compare and pass it as `data` in this script but in the last row when you are choosing the actual rows use the original matrix.

Comment: @ Mohsen, hello, how could I modify the program if I want to select the rows while the element in column 2 which has no occurrence in column 1 as well? e.g. if the row [24 78] is unique and was selected. However, 24 already appear in a row we selected previously [6 24]. In a word I want element to appear only once regardless of the column, thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Hi I just figured out how to do it myself :) Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I just figure out how to do it :) Thank you all for help :)

```
for j = 1:500 % random number, big enough to find out all my pairs
    k = 1;
    while any(bsxfun(@eq, store, data(k,2))|bsxfun(@eq, store, data(k,1)))
        k = k+1;
       if k > length(data)-1, break, end  

end

    pair(j,:) = data(k,:);
    store(2*j-1) = pair(j,1);
    store(2*j) = pair(j,2);
    fprintf('the loop we are at is %d \n',j);

end
```